# What is list not defined and result not defined in react/jsx-no-undef and no-undef

Tags: reactjs

Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
  Line 37:10:  'List' is not defined    react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 39:13:  'result' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 40:16:  'List' is not defined    react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Can you share your related codes also?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-ritchie-fzcc8?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Look like you're using some variables which is not defined. Check where you take `List` and `result`. It's better to use eslint to prevent this kind of errors at the beginning